# Expecting Array[String] but type is Array[Byte]

Tags: scala

Experimenting with map, flatMap and flatten and the following output is unexpected :

```
  case class T(data: String)
  val s = Set(T("1") , T("2"))
  val a: Array[Byte] = s.map(transaction => transaction.data).flatten.toArray
```

Should `a` not be of type `Array[String]`? , as `data` is of type `String`. Why is `a` of type `Array[Byte]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to flatten is happening on a `Set[String]`. The `String` is treated something like an `Iterable[Byte]` (since that's more or less what a string is). So the flatten call is effecitively taking a `Set[Iterable[Byte]]` and flattening it into a `Set[Byte]` (which you then convert to an `Array[Byte]`).

Drop the flatten call and you'll get what you're after.

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GqQiOHiWSZ6GKwdoM41yAg